# Pass variable into constructer from within listener

Tags: java, blackberry

The below code generates a buttons within a loop and attempts to pass a string parameter to a button listener from within the button. I'm not achieving desired result. When I press each unique 'buttonField' object the variable 'key' is the same value on the new screen. Is below code correct ?

Thanks

```
Enumeration keysEnumeration = table.keys();
    while(keysEnumeration.hasMoreElements()){

            key = (String)keysEnumeration.nextElement();
     buttonField.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {  
             public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {  
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new Screen(key));
            }  
        }); 
        add(buttonField);    
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `key` is a field in the enclosing class.

Remove that. Make the key assignment  declaration and `final`:

```
final String key = (String)keysEnumeration.nextElement();
```

That will give easy instance of your listener a different `key` variable and so the appropriate key.

You might also want to remove and mutable statics you may have, use Java 2 collections (some of Swing is still bound to 1.1, which is unfortunate because it wasn't actually in 1.1) and generics (as introduced in 2004!). (Edit: See you have the blackberry tag. Are they still around?)

Comment: Generics not supported in the blackberry jde im using

Comment: Thanks for the help, its now working. do you mind elaborating why key needs to be final ? –

Comment: @user470184 The Java spec requires it. It could have been defined not to be necessary, and either the inner class references the field (a final reference to the reference) or makes a copy of the value (which is a reference). Either option can lead to non-obvious behaviour of specific code. Perhaps better to make the field effectively or implicitly final. So Java, thus far, has stuck with a functional-like of approach of having the variable not vary. Lambdas to be in JDK8 are the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Enumeration keysEnumeration = table.keys();

    while (keysEnumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
        final String key = (String) keysEnumeration.nextElement();
        buttonField.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {
            public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
                UiApplication.getUiApplication()
                        .pushScreen(new Screen(key));
            }
        });
        add(buttonField);
    }
```

`key` should be final to be accessible inside the anonymous inner class.

Comment: Thanks for the help, its now working. do you mind elaborating why key needs to be final ?